# swift: how to split a string and remove first element?

Tags: arrays, swift, mutable

I want to create an array out of text split and then remove any items I want. The code snippet doesn't compile because a is not mutable.
What should I do?

```
var a = []
// ...
a = split(text, { $0 == "\n"}, maxSplit: Int.max, allowEmptySlices: false)
let sentence = a.removeAtIndex(0)
```

Comment: `a` is mutable and that code compiles (and runs) without problem for me.

Comment: @Martin R, I updated the question to introduce the actually code which makes the compilation break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var a = []
```

defines `a` as an `NSArray`, and that does not have a `removeAtIndex()`. Replacing that
with

```
var a : [String]
```

should solve the problem. Alternatively, declare and assign the variable in one step:

```
var a = split(text, { $0 == "\n"}, maxSplit: Int.max, allowEmptySlices: false)
```

Comment: Thanks. And is there a way to set a NSMutableArray straight in swift? Additional question is: is there any performance penalty or advantage to stick with swift array or NSArray?

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca arrays created with `var` in swift are mutable from creation, `let` defines immutability. `var a: [String]` is actually a swift array that is interchangeable with Objective-C. As for performance penalty I am unsure, however I understand it is always best to go with immutable objects (was in an WWDC talk) reference for swift arrays https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Answer (score 0):

Modify your array declaration?

```
var a = Array<String>()
let text = "this has \nsome words"
a = split(text, { $0 == "\n"}, maxSplit: Int.max, allowEmptySlices: false)
let sentence = a.removeAtIndex (0)
print(a)
```

prints "[some words]"